# How to include a file when writing a custom man page?

Tags: bash, manpage

Currently I just copy the source file for my custom man page into place like this:

```bsh
SOURCE=man/myManPage.1
DEST_DIR=/usr/local/share/man/man.1
sudo install -g 0 -o 0 -m 0644 "$SOURCE" "$DEST_DIR/"
yes | sudo gzip "$DEST_DIR/myManPage.1"
```

Works fine.

Now I want to be able to include a file containing a footer. Looks like using the `.so` macro in my man page source file might be one way forward:

```
.so footer.tmac
```

The `.mso` macro might be another option:

```
.mso footer.tmac
```

The problem with both of those approaches is that I am not actually running `groff` when moving the man page into place, I just copy the source into a `.gz` file and the include file is not around on the user machine so the footer does not display.

Perhaps I need to preprocess the man source somehow so a complete file is generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, using `soelim` as suggested by @meuh:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Publishes man.1 files in ~/myman/
# Preprocesses .so statements by including the specified files

INCLUDED=included

function publish {
  SOURCE="~/myman/$INCLUDED/$1"
  if [[ ! -f "$SOURCE" ]]; then
    echo "Fatal: '$SOURCE' does not exist"
    exit 2
  fi

  I="${1##*.}"
  DEST_DIR=/usr/local/share/man/man${I}
  sudo mkdir -p ${DEST_DIR}
  sudo rm -f "$DEST_DIR/$1.gz"
  sudo install -g 0 -o 0 -m 0644 "$SOURCE" "$DEST_DIR/"
  echo "Creating $DEST_DIR/$1.gz"
  yes | sudo gzip "$DEST_DIR/$1"
}

cd "~/myman"
mkdir -p ${INCLUDED}
for CMD in *.1; do
  soelim -I ./ $CMD > $INCLUDED/$CMD
  pushd ${INCLUDED} > /dev/null
  publish "${CMD}"
  popd > /dev/null
done

sudo mandb
```

Here is a man source file with two `.so` include directives:

```
.TH man-course 1 "03 May 2019" "1.0" "cad-course man page"
.SH NAME
cad-course \- Cadenza Client command for authoring course content
.SH SYNOPSIS
cad course id aa | audioFromTitles | dw | fetch [-r] | gitNewRepo | publish | pp | status
.SH DESCRIPTION
\fBcad-course\fR is a Cadenza Client curriculum management command for authoring course-level content.
.so cad-description.tmac
.SH OPTIONS
The cad-course command takes sub-commands and options.
.SH EXAMPLES
  cad course 40 dw               # Launch DreamWeaver on content for course #40 (Intro to Scala)
.PP
  cad course 40 dw               # Launch DreamWeaver on content for course #40
.PP
  cad course 40 audioFromTitles  # Build a new Adobe Audition audio project from course #40 transcript titles
.PP
  cad course 40 gitNewRepo       # Wipe out any existing GitHub project for course #40 and make a new one,
check in current stuff. Use regular git commands as content is authored.
.PP
  cad course 40 fetch            # (Re)download all of the content for course #40's courses from the active database and the active S3 buckets.
If uncommitted changes to course's git repo, ask user if the changes should
be committed before fetching. If no git repo, makes one.
.PP
  cad course -r 40 fetch         # Also recurses by fetching sections & their lectures.
.so cad-footer.tmac
```

Here is `cad-description.tmac`:

```
The complete list of curriculum management commands is: cad-site, cad-group, cad-course, cad-section and cad-lecture.
```

Here is `cad-footer.tmac`:

```
.SH SEE ALSO
 cad-course(1),cad-group(1),cad-install(1),cad-lecture(1),cad-publish(1),cad-section(1),cad-site(1),cad-status(1),cad-status(1),bash(8)
.SH BUGS
No known bugs.
.SH AUTHOR
Michael Slinn (mslinn@micronauticsresearch.com)
```

This is the output from `man cad`:

```
man(1)                                                                                 cad man page                                                                                man(1)

NAME
       cad - Cadenza Client command-line interface

SYNOPSIS
       cad install status  # TODO What other options might apply?

DESCRIPTION
       cad is a command-line interface for cadenzaClient

OPTIONS
       The cad command takes sub-commands and options.

EXAMPLES
       cad -h

SEE ALSO
        cad-course(1),cad-group(1),cad-install(1),cad-lecture(1),cad-publish(1),cad-section(1),cad-site(1),cad-status(1),cad-status(1),bash(8)

BUGS
       No known bugs.

AUTHOR
       Michael Slinn (mslinn@micronauticsresearch.com)

1.0                                                                                    03 May 2019                                                                                 man(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [soelim](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/soelim.1.html) command provided with `groff` to do exactly this.

> soelim reads files and replaces lines of the form
>        `.so file`
>   by the contents of file.

Comment: Looks perfect. Will try it out. I essentially wrote a homegrown version of soelim yesterday, but it would be better to use a standard like soelim than maintaining my own version for no reason. Thanks!